# Prevent body from scrolling when side panel opens

Tags: jquery, html, css, panel

I toggle my panel by click on my button cd-btn which call a new class .cd-panel.is-visible

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
//open the lateral panel
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
});
```

the .is-visible class:

```
 .cd-panel.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;}
```

I would like to prevent the body from scrolling when the panel opens or is-visible. So far I have achieved this by:

```
$(".cd-panel").mouseenter(function(){
  $("body").css("overflow", "hidden"); 
}).mouseleave(function(){
  $("body").css("overflow", "visible");
});
```

which works only when i enter or leave the panel with my mouse. But I would like to achieve this by just opening the panel. 
How can I add the overflow:hidden style to the body when the panel opens and then when I close it it would turn the overflow to visible.
I would also like to add position:fixed to the body when my panel opens and it would return to position:relative after closing the panel

Comment: Let me know if the answer works.

Comment: it's probably best to add a class to body, toggling its overflow, position and height value. you might need to add `height:100%` to body for the overflow to work properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might have figured out what was the problem by reading your(OPs) & @Praveen-Kumar comments.

Instead of checking `:visible` just check if the element has the class `is-visible` or not, which eventually decides whether the element is visible or not.

So your code becomes...

```
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
  if ($('.cd-panel').hasClass("is-visible")) // Changed this line from your link.
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  else
    $("body").css("overflow", "visible");
});
```

Comment: My pleasure, also all credit goes to @Praveen Kumar since I just studied his efforts and found what the problem could be. :)

Comment: absolutely, I have already explained to him the situation but I cannot accept 2 answers, so thank you @Praveen Kumar

Answer (score 2):

Set the `.css` here:

```
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible');
  if ($('.cd-panel').is(":visible"))
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
  else
    $("body").css("overflow", "visible");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, it did set the body overflow to hidden when the panel opens but when I toggle it the overflow stays hidden and wont set it to visible

Comment: @user3194137 Try changing the condition to `if (!$('.cd-panel').is(":visible"))` and see if it works?

Comment: in this case the overflow stays visible constantly after clicking the cd-btn

Comment: @user3194137 Okay great. I give up! `:P`

Comment: could you maybe help with what one of the answers users meant with this?  
"it's probably best to add a class to body, toggling its overflow, position and height value. you might need to add height:100% to body for the overflow to work properly"   how to toggle the overflow, position and height value for the body with a class?

Comment: @user3194137 I am kinda confused with the actual requirement itself now. Kindly tell me in simple words, what are you trying to achieve. An image illustration would be awesome. `:)`

Comment: if I upload my current solution to my domain and send you a link?

Comment: @user3194137 That would be the best. `:)`

Comment: @user3194137 Can I suggest you an alternative? Tough to examine now.

Comment: go on, more than happy to experiment

Comment: @user3194137 It is `1 am` here and I am half drowsy. Lemme know if you encounter any issues. I will help you once I wake up. Need to rush to office tomorrow morning. I have just 4 hours to sleep.

Comment: considering the whole conversation you have figured out the code but it didn't work in the end, yet another user after seeing our conversation figured out the right code. Sorry that I cannot accept 2 answers

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.cd-btn').on('click', function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('.cd-panel').toggleClass('is-visible'); 
    if ($('.cd-panel').hasClass("is-visible")) { 
        $('body').css({
            height: '100%',
            overflow: 'hidden'
        })
    } else {
        $('body').css({
          height: 'auto',
          overflow: 'visible'
        }) 
    }
});
```